# Enity Framework Update Database tries to recreate existing __EFMigrationHistory table

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an empty database and I use the code-first approach. I have my models and dbcontext defined and I run

```
Add-Migration InitialMigration -OutputDir MigrationsPostgres -Context DbContextDevelopmentPostgres
```

this creates an initial migration with all tables etc. After this update the database using

```
 Update-Database -Context DbContextDevelopmentPostgres
```

the update process works fine and all tables are created;

now i add another property one of my models; I ran

```
Add-Migration TestMigration -OutputDir MigrationsPostgres -Context DbContextDevelopmentPostgres
```

this creates a new migration file with only the changes i made in the model

however if if now run

```
Update-Database -Context GeophysicsDbContextDevelopmentPostgres
```

again it outputs the following

```
    SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid=c.relnamespace
    WHERE n.nspname='public' AND
          c.relname='__EFMigrationsHistory'
)
SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid=c.relnamespace
    WHERE n.nspname='public' AND
          c.relname='__EFMigrationsHistory'
)
Failed executing DbCommand (10ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "__EFMigrationsHistory" (
    "MigrationId" character varying(150) NOT NULL,
    "ProductVersion" character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK___EFMigrationsHistory" PRIMARY KEY ("MigrationId")
);
```

stating that the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table already exists, which is right because it was create with the initial Migration

I am using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.25` `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 6.0.25` `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 6.0.22`

I have used the same methodology with oracle and it just worked fine, (lower versions of EnityframeworkCore though)

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

i found the problem, i am using a custom schema to add all the tables und the __EFMigrationHistory Tables is also added to that given Schema, however the checks beforehand are run agains the public schema where the __EFMigrationHistory Table never extists, still don't know how to solve this

Comment: Try to create [idempotent script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#idempotent-sql-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

I used modelbuilder to set schema and updated new model normally to table.

```
    public class MyContext :DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Database=my_db;Username=postgres;Password=xxxxxx");
        }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }  //Add a new Model

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("custome_schema");
        }
    }
```

[image]
Although "__EFMigrationsHistory" is still in public schema.